# VueJS / Vue Router - create details page from list item?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I have a list of items (taken from a JSON file) which I currently loop through, however I wish to create a details page for each of these items (incorporating VueRouter).

Any pointers on how to achieve this? I'm currently stuck on passing the data to the details page template.

Thanks

```
    <ul>
    <li v-for="projects in projects.projects">
    {{ projects.name }}
    <router-link :to="profileLink" class="button is-outlined">View Details</router-link>
    {{ projects.coding }}
    { projects.design }}
    {{ projects.description }}
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 18):

See those links :

- https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html
- https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html

With your use case what you could do is:

1. set up a new named route called details:

   ```
       {
         path: '/project/:projectId/details',
         name: 'details',
         component: Details,
         props: true,
       }
   ```

   Every time you want to redirect a user to details page, use this route.
   The :projectId means it's dynamic, you can provide any id, it will always redirect to the component Details you created to display a project's details.
2. Create a new router link in your list like so:

   ```
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'details', params: { projectId: project.id }}">{{project.name}}</router-link>
   ```
3. Inside your component details, you have to declare route params as props, for instance `props: ["id"],`. You can then access it in your component with this.id.

Comment: One issue, when I reload a details page the info is wiped, so I just left with a template?

Comment: Where do you load your data in the details page ?

Comment: I'm using the following syntax in my template:
`<h1>{{ $route.params.projectId.name }}</h1>`

I've been reading on state management, and using local storage?

Comment: It's completely normal if your template is empty.
In your template, you only have access to `$route.params.projectId`, **not the object**.
You have to use it to retrieve your object either with a simple search inside your json file/object, or by setting up a vuex store (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to vuex, would you be able to provide a brief example of how I should implement this with this scenario?

Comment: Take a look at the exemples from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router. 
Clone or download the repository and follow the setup instructions.
Pay particularly attention to 'data-fetching' and 'route-props' examples. Those are the one you're looking for

Comment: Just use `props: true` at the details route definition, and at the template use `projectId` directly, instead of `$route.params.projectId`. This is suggested way at [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) (as opposed to couple template with `$route.params`).

@CorentinAndré I'd update answer for anyone who would land here in future.